# Django tests - launch multiple test servers that could communicate?

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing

I wonder if it is possible to run django tests that could simulate the existence of multiple servers, using TestCase or LiveServerTestCase.

For instance, I would like to launch a "client server" on localhost port 8081 using Firefox and a "resource server" on port 8082 using Chrome. The client server should be able to make requests to the resource server in order to retrieve json data. Each server should be configurable with his own settings. In short I would like to do something like

```
MyTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    @override_settings(DATABASE={... client db config ...})
    def launch_client(self):
        self.client = webdriver.Firefox() # on port 8081

    @override_settings(DATABASE={... resource db config ...})
    def launch_resource(self):
        self.resource = webdriver.Chrome() # on port 8082   

    def test_get_json(self):
        self.client.get('http://127.0.0:8082/get/data/') # which should return data from the resource server ...
```

So far I've come with the following solutions, which do not work:

1. The most basic: launching two webdrivers at once using LiveServerTestCase. Ie

   ```
   class MySeleniumTests(LiveServerTestCase):

       @classmethod
       def setUpClass(cls):
           cls.selenium_chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
           cls.selenium_firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
           super(MySeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()
   ```

but this does not work because both webdrivers will run on the same port and will not allow different settings on each server.

2. Using django nose with the multiprocess option (https://github.com/nosedjango/nosedjango#parallel-test-running-via-multiprocess). But this simply runs tests separatly.
3. Using pyvows as described here (https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-testing-with-django-and-pyvows/). This option actually launches multiple applications on multiple ports, but yelds very inconsistent results (threads not finding their servers, etc). Furthemore, requesting one server from the other does not work without hacks.

Any thoughts? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own LiveServerTestCase mixin using multiple LiveServerThread instead of just one.

Comment: This seems to be much harder than it sounds. Perhaps if you launch the same server twice that *could* work, but if you want to launch two different servers, you'd need to change the settings before launching the second one, and my attempts to patch out `django.conf.settings` did not work. I would love to see some example code if someone can point to some though!